# Bluetooth File Transfer Error Between 2 Computers

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, bluetooth

I have two machines that I am attempting to connect using Bluetooth. One machine running windows 7 has bluetooth built in. The other machine running Windows XP has a bluetooth USB dongle that I am using and windows recognized the the bluetooth and installed the driver itself. No additional software came with the dongle.

Here is my issue:

When I attempt to transfer a file from the Windows 7 Machine to the Win XP machine I get the following error:

[image: Screenshot of Error]

Both computers tell me that I am connected and I can transfer from windows XP to the windows 7 machine without issue.

Am I missing some software on the Windows XP Machine? How do I fix the error and transfer files from the Windows 7 Machine to the Windows XP Machine?

***EDIT:*** I attempted to download and use the OBEX File Transfer Program (program by [Medieval](http://www.medieval.it/blueftp-pc/menu-id-70.html)) and the program said OBEX File Service not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect that this is a problem with the wrong BlueTooth profile being selected within XP (or perhaps 7, but I'm leaning towards XP). [Here's a web page that shows how to update the Bluetooth stack on XP](http://oreilly.com/pub/a/windows/archive/bluetooth.html?page=2). I'm not a fan of linking to a page as the only set of instructions in a forum post because links can die. As such, I'll reproduce the instructions in my own words, however I will not copy the pictures from the page.

1. Go to the Computer Management MMC: start >> run >> compmgmt.msc >> [enter key]
2. Open up the "Device Manager" node on the left hand side
3. Open up the "BlueTooth Radios" node within Device Manager
4. Right click on "Generic Blue Tooth Radio" and select "Update Driver"
5. Click "No, Not this time" in the "Hardware Update Wizard" dialog box and then click "next"
6. Click "Install from a list or specific location" in the "Hardware Update Wizard" dialog box and then click "next"
7. Click "Don't search. I will choose the driver to install" and then click "next"
8. Make sure that your generic BlueTooth radio is selected and then click "Have Disk"
9. Click the "Browse" button
10. Make sure that the model for the drivers for your USB dongle are selected and then click "next"
11. The drivers for your dongle will be installed.

This may be what resets your BlueTooth to the proper profile for file transfers.

Comment: I do not have any drivers nor can I find them for my Bluetooth Radio. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP had generic Bluetooth drivers as of SP2. If there was no software with the dongle, it should've been supported by the stock drivers. Here's what you need to do to troubleshoot the issue (in no particular order):

- Go to the dongle manufacturer's website and see if they have Bluetooth drivers for download.
- Get [Broadcom's driver updating utility for WIDCOMM Bluetooth devices](http://www.broadcom.com/support/bluetooth/update.php) and see if it will recognize your dongle.
- Connect the dongle to the Windows 7 machine and see how it installs there.

OBEX is a software feature not hardware so the problem is in the drivers.